# Decoding JSON data from QueryDict

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am sending JSON data to my django program. I am facing problems decoding the data.

In javascript, I convert an object which encapsulates two arrays into JSON, and read it back.

Javascript:

```
data = {
    "RegAvStart": reg_start,
    "RegAvStop": reg_end
};
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
console.log(data);
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log("JSON:" + jsondata);
```

Here, both reg_start and reg_end are arrays of strings.
In the console I get:

```
JSON:"&RegAvStart%5B%5D=05%3A00%20AM&RegAvStart%5B%5D=05%3A30%20PM&RegAvStop%5B%5D=08%3A00%20AM&RegAvStop%5B%5D=09%3A30%20PM"
```

My django(python) code:

```
def save_doctorslots(request, cliniclabel, doctor_id):
    doctor_id=int(doctor_id)
    doc = get_object_or_404(doctor, docid=doctor_id)
    cl = Clinic.objects.get(label=cliniclabel)
    print("Clinic name", cl.name)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg ="Received SaveSlots data for doctor %d clinic %s" % (doctor_id, cliniclabel)
        print(msg)
        print(request.POST)
        regavst = request.POST.get('RegAvStart[]')
        print(type(regavst))
        if not regavst is None:
            regular_available_start = json.loads(regavst)
        else:
            print("Didnt get regular available hours")
```

Output:

```
Received SaveSlots data for doctor 1 clinic joelent
<QueryDict: {'RegAvStart[]': ['05:00 AM', '05:30 PM'], 'RegAvStop[]': ['08:00 AM', '09:30 PM']}>
<class 'str'>
2018-10-04 10:45:53,000 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /clinic/joelent/doctor/save/slots/1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/joel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joel/myappointments/clinic/views.py", line 261, in save_doctorslots
    regular_available_start = json.loads(regavst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: Try to avoid the `stringify` function. That is try this, `var jsondata = data;`

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for JSON here at all. You have already serialized the data so it is in form-encoded format; doing `JSON.stringify` just adds another pointless level of serialization. Remove that line and send `data` directly in your Ajax function.